# How do I make these two divs the same height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some groups of content which consists of two divs, both divs contain text, and I want the second div of each set to match the height of the first.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lighty_46/59Rhn/)

HTML (Cannot be changed unfortunately)

```
<!-- group one -->
<div class="item">
    .... content here
</div>

<div class="item_open">
    .... content here too
</div>

<!-- group two -->
<div class="item">
    .... completely different content here
</div>

<div class="item_open">
    .... some more content here too
</div>
```

Comment: Is the content dynamically changed after page load?

Comment: It's going to be responsive and any text in the second div will have overflow: scroll; on .... if I need to I will just run it on re-size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.item_open').height(function(){
 return $(this).prev().height();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/59Rhn/1/)

Comment: That's perfect thanks! I knew it would be a fairly simple solution, it's just figuring out how to use it. I was originally thinking of going down the route of .closest(), but figured it was better I ask here first.

Answer (score 2):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2RLqE/)

```
$('.item_open').height(function(){
    return $(this).prev().height();
});
```

[.height()](https://api.jquery.com/height/#height-functionindex--height)

[.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that what you are looking for could be found here: http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

(Using CSS and not JQuery)

Comment: I've used that method before and it's good but wouldn't work for what I'm doing. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle using jQuery to achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/59Rhn/4/

```
$(".item_open").each(function(){
    $(this).height($(this).prev().height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change HTML, you can try in this way..

```
var $item = $(document).find('.item'); // find first tag item
var $itemNext = $item.next();          // return item_open
$($item, $itemNext).css({
   height: '100px'
});
```